# Replacing /odom topic for turtlebot

Tags: navigation, odometry, turtlebot, ros-hydro, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a vicon system rather than a gyro and encoders to track my Turtlebot's pose. Only problem is, I'm not sure how to modify the /odom topic to take only my vicon data (it currently takes both the vicon data output from my custom node as well as the encoder/gyro data from a turtlebot_navigation node).

Does anyone have experience with this? I'm not sure how to replace the /odom topic properly!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194245/replacing-/odom-topic-for-turtlebot/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will want to copy and modify the appropriate turtlebot_navigation launch files and remap the /odom topic of the standard publisher to an unused or alternative topic such as /odom_unused so that it won't conflict with your other odom measurements.

Note, there are probably cleaner ways to build the integration than publishing odom from the vicon system, such as replacing the localization instead of the odometry.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2